# How to load a KML from Google Drive in Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap, kml

I am trying to display a KML file (loading it directly from Google Drive, e.g. `https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ngi_nLWEYt-aCzX0dGioa8bP3K-UbUNP/view?usp=sharing`) on a map using Leaflet. With the code below,this `Error` triggers:

> ```
> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Bounds are not valid.
> at i.fitBounds (leaflet.js:5)
> at index.html:45
> ```

What is wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"> </meta>
        <title>Map</title>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "lib/leaflet.css"/>
        <script src = "lib/leaflet.js"></script>
        <script src = "lib/L.KML.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
        #pozadina{background-image: linear-gradient(to right,lightblue, rgb(36, 112, 226));}
        #map{
            height: 720px;
            width: 86%;
            padding-left: 7%;
            padding-right: 7%;
            }
        #naslov{
            color: rgb(15, 15, 199);
            font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
            text-align: center;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body id="pozadina">
        <h1 id="naslov">Map</h1>
        <div id = "map"></div>

        <script>
            // Make basemap
            const map = new L.Map('map', { center: new L.LatLng(44.786568, 20.448921), zoom: 11 });
            const osm = new L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png');

            map.addLayer(osm);

            // Load kml file
            fetch("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/" +"https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ngi_nLWEYt-aCzX0dGioa8bP3K-UbUNP/view?usp=sharing")
                .then(res => res.text())
                .then(kmltext => {
                    
                    const parser = new DOMParser();
                    const kml = parser.parseFromString(kmltext, 'text/xml');
                    const track = new L.KML(kml);
                    map.addLayer(track);
                    console.log(track.getBounds());
                    map.fitBounds(track.getBounds()); //here is a problem
                });
                
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What is the result of your fetch with the exact URL string you are building?

Comment: It seems to be malformed XML - in fact, it looks like a plain-text error message complaining about missing [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers) in fetch. Even when providing the right headers, the result looks to be a HTML document instead of KML.

Answer (score 2):

The KML file you are linking to (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ngi_nLWEYt-aCzX0dGioa8bP3K-UbUNP/view?usp=sharing) is on Google Drive, and you are pointing at the Share link. That share link loads and HTML page for the file, and does not download the file itself.  You need a URL that directly downloads the actual KML file.  The Google Drive interface does not provide this type of direct link, but there are instructions out there that will show you the necessary URL pattern to construct such a link.  Alternatively, you could re-host the KML file on some other service which provides an easy direct link to the file itself.